# Wouldn't Charge Flow On Power Lines Due to Capacitance

Tags: capacitor, mains, high-voltage

If I touch one line of an exposed power line (say 300 kV AC) and the rest of my body is freely suspended (only in contact with air), am I not forming a capacitor (to ground)?  If I am, are electrons not flowing in/out of me as I charge/discharge?

Is my understanding that this forms a capacitor incorrect, or is the capacitance such that electron flow is small despite the high voltages associated with power lines?

Comment: [Similar Q&A here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239387/41836).

Answer (score 3):

Any situation where you have something with charge, some dielectric spacing, and something else with charge will have capacitance. So pretty much everything.

In your case, the capacitance is just very, very small. Small capacitance gives a large impedance to both AC and DC.

When you have *direct* contact with the earth, body capacitance to earth is usually spec'd at 100pF (already very small). If you were floating in mid-air as you say, this adds more spacing further decreasing this capacitance (with respect to earth), as you would find from this formula the effect of increasing \$ d \$.

[image]

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very much so, for an excellent visuals, see:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YmFHAFYwmY
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPNK7bc2qvM

Note that these linemen are wearing Faraday (metal mesh) suits.